# Unable to pass parameter from directive to controller function

Tags: angularjs

I can call the function from my directive but the parameter keeps being passed as undefined.

Here's the line from the directive

```
<input ng-click="delete(0)" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Feed" />
```

and here's the directive

```
<testdirective delete="deleteFeed()"></testdirective>
```

And here's the function

```
 $scope.deleteFeed = function(x){
  console.log(x);
  $scope.tweets.splice(x, 1);
}
```

and finally the directive itself

```
app.directive("testdirective", function() {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  templateUrl: 'app/main/tweetboard.html', 
  scope: {
    delete:'&'
  },

};
```

});

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with a different function name? `delete` is reserved in JS, could be causing some issues.

Comment: Just tried it and got the same response. But good call anyway, I renamed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following 2 things:

1. Replace the directive using by this:
   `<testdirective delete="deleteFeed(feed)"></testdirective>`
2. The pointed line from directive replace by
   `<input ng-click="delete({feed:0})" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Feed" />`

The point with `@` binding form is that a function wrapper will be created & it will point to the original function. 
To call the original function with parameter you need to pass an object to the wrapper function, the key of the object is the name of the parameter.

Example from official [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> Given `<widget my-attr="count = count + value">` and widget definition
>   of scope: `{ localFn:'&myAttr' }`, then isolate scope property `localFn`
>   will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value`
>   expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope
>   via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a
>   map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn.
>   For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can
>   specify the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({amount:22})`

Answer (score 0):

try as attribute instead of scope

```
app.directive("testdirective", function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      templateUrl: 'app/main/tweetboard.html', 
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) { 
          if(attr.deleteFeed)
              scope.$apply(attr.deleteFeed);
      }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<testdirective delete="deleteFeed()"></testdirective>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution:

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/a00DDp?p=preview)

You forgot to pass in the parameter so it was always undefined.

// Code goes here

```
var app  =angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('testController', function($scope){
  $scope.x = "test";
  $scope.deleteFeed = function(x){
    alert(x);
  }
})

app.directive("testdirective", function() {
return {
restrict: "E",
template: '<input ng-click="delete(x)" type="submit" id="submit" value="Delete Feed" />',
scope: {
    delete:'&'
}
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple way to pass pa-ram in function from directive to parent controller:

In parent view:

```
<div  menubar activatetab="cdCtrl.activateTab(id)"></div>
```

In directive:

```
<div ng-click="activatetab({id:10})>Click here...</div>
```

In parent controller:

```
$scope.activateTab(id) =function(){    
                alert(id);
```

}

Hope it working for you!!